# what best way to install latest GIMP in (K)Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, gimp

The official ubuntu 18.04 repo stops at 2.8

On the official download page, they suggest using flatpak, although non better specified "limitations".

There is an unofficial PPA provided by a GIMP's developer (Otto Kesselgulasch)

What's your advice about it?